# How to store user's profile picture in mysql

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I am developing a chat application for iOS.

In this app, the users can set up an image as their profile picture.

So my question is, how can i be able to store images in mysql ?

I have seen that many people say, just store the link to the image(on device) in mysql, but how will the images be available on different iOS Devices, from a database right ?

I have also tried using BLOB, but when the table rows are displayed(json encoded), the value for BLOB field comes out to be NULL.

Please answer in brief.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you saving the images on the device or retrieving it from a webserver?

Comment: If he is developing a chat application...? he sure has a webserver, don't you think? :D

Comment: I want to retrieve the images from a web server...

Comment: Next to the answer below, you could store the image in the database as base64. This would however increase its size by 33%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly simple :) The physical image will be stored on a server and you will store in your DB only the image name, or the relative path to the image, or however you want it. So, if you like, you will have to store in your DB a "pointer" to that image.

So:
- Image in folder on the server
- In DB -> path/to/file or file_name.format OR if you know you path, and you know your format just file_name

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Thanks,

But i don't have much experience with all this...

How do i upload images on my server via the iOS App ?
Won't that require something like filezilla and all ?

Comment: you have to use C# code... unfortunately, I don't know C# so I can't help here...

Comment: C sharp... It's object oriented C++ (more about it here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx37x362.aspx) or any other development enviroment for iOS apps :D

Comment: @AresDraguna You might want to do some more research.

Comment: @AshishGogna iOS apps can be coded in C# using [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/platform).

Comment: research about what? :D this question was not about iOS app environments... it was about how to store images on DB :-? I don't know iOS :)

Comment: @AresDraguna As I read your previous comment, you said C++ isn't object-orientated.

Comment: no, I said that C# is object oriented C++ as in: C# is only object oriented... At least this is what I know :)

Comment: @AresDraguna C# isn't only object orientated. As I said earlier, you might want to do some more research. Also, I hereby take my leave from this utterly useless and time-wasting discussion. Your answer, however, seems the best option the asker has.

Comment: @0x47686F7374 I never said I know C# or any other iOS environments... And I don't need to do research :) I don't need it :P

Comment: Okay so now i have the file name of the image in db table field.
How do i json encode it and display the image ?

Comment: like you would json encode anything else from the DB

Comment: Now it only displays file location/name like so - "dp/test.png"...
How to get the actual image ?

Comment: are you kidding me? :) I dk... in HTML for example, we use something like this: <img src="dp/test.png" /> where img is the image tag and src tells the browser where the source of the image is... find the equivalent for the programming language that you use :)

Comment: btw, please accept my answer if it answered your original question, so it may help others in your situation ;)

Comment: Can you tell me how to display image from this line of code ?
echo json_encode($row['dp']);...

And ya, i'll be accepting your answer...

Comment: if `$row['dp']` is your image path, then, in html it will be <img src="<?php echo $row['dp']; ?>" /> but I really do not know iOS and I don't know the equivalent. Also, you are encoding the result? then your JSON will be something like {dp: /path/to/file} so upon decoding you will have it in a array just as you have it now... find the equivalent for what I told you and you will be fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

May be late But I just found way to do that.

Way 1: Get image from user and rename with the id (Pref. Primary key) and in Your public_html create folder for images. Set proper permissions for that folder. and save image in that folder and the url of that image will be stored DB column . Like

https://www.example.com/images/user1.png do in that style.

Way 2: use other things to rename that image like user's email,username etc

way 3: In above 2 cases it may happen that other users,hackers may try to download images by using IDs,emails etc.
That's why , another way you can do is you can generate a hash for profile and check if the hash already exists in column if exits then generate another one. Likely I don't think there is possibility of generating similar hashes.but you may check to avoid error in future. and now rename image using that generated hash.

You may also reduce size of that link column using only storing generated hash and in your app declare some variables and achieve

https://www.example.com/images/generated_hash.png

here the url will be same in all columns excluding that hash key.
you may only store that hashes.

Hope it will help

Reference from : https://www.techupdates.live/how-to-save-profile-picture-in-php-in-5-simple-steps/

Comment: replying to 
another way you can do is you can generate a hash for profile and check if the hash already exists in column if exits then generate another one. 

= you can generate some random hash and append it with  primary id. this will be unique random hash always